# MySQL UNION ALL (Full Join) with conditional aggregation

Tags: mysql, aggregate, outer-join

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Agreement` (
  `AID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FLAGS` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`AID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Assessment` (
  `ASMID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AID` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Amount` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `Description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ASMID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Payment` (
  `RID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AID` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ASMID` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Amount` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `Description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RID`)
);
```

And I'm inserting one Agreement, three Assessment, five Payment rows mentioned as below:

```
INSERT INTO Agreement(FLAGS) VALUES(0);
INSERT INTO Assessment(AID, Amount, Description) VALUES (1, 1200, "Rent");
INSERT INTO Assessment(AID, Amount, Description) VALUES (1, 20, "Damage - car break");
INSERT INTO Assessment(AID, Amount, Description) VALUES (1, 500, "Damage - vehicle");
INSERT INTO Payment(AID, ASMID, Amount, Description) VALUES(1, 1, 500, "Rent Fee");
INSERT INTO Payment(AID, ASMID, Amount, Description) VALUES(1, 1, 600, "Rent Fee");
INSERT INTO Payment(AID, ASMID, Amount, Description) VALUES(1, 2, 20, "Damage Fee");
INSERT INTO Payment(AID, Amount, Description) VALUES(1, 600, "Deposit Fee");
INSERT INTO Payment(AID, Amount, Description) VALUES(1, 50, "Application Fee");
```

and When I see the data, so it should look like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Agreement;
+-----+-------+
| AID | FLAGS |
+-----+-------+
|   1 |     0 |
+-----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Assessment;
+-------+-----+-----------+--------------------+
| ASMID | AID | Amount    | Description        |
+-------+-----+-----------+--------------------+
|     1 |   1 | 1200.0000 | Rent               |
|     2 |   1 |   20.0000 | Damage - car break |
|     3 |   1 |  500.0000 | Damage - vehicle   |
+-------+-----+-----------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Payment;
+-----+-----+-------+----------+-----------------+
| RID | AID | ASMID | Amount   | Description     |
+-----+-----+-------+----------+-----------------+
|   1 |   1 |     1 | 500.0000 | Rent Fee        |
|   2 |   1 |     1 | 600.0000 | Rent Fee        |
|   3 |   1 |     2 |  20.0000 | Damage Fee      |
|   4 |   1 |     0 | 600.0000 | Deposit Fee     |
|   5 |   1 |     0 |  50.0000 | Application Fee |
+-----+-----+-------+----------+-----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, any Agreement has multiple Assessments all need to be paid in near future. It may have multiple Payments which might be associated with Assessment (i.e., Rent Fee) or might be not (i.e., Application Fee).

Now, in reality, there are multiple Agreements which have multiple Assessments and multiple Payments.

Now I want the result that covers all of the rows from both tables `Assessment` and `Payment` associated with `Agreement` GROUPED BY first Agreement, second Assessment. Additionally, I need to aggregate AMOUNT as `PaymentsApplied` from the table `Payment` table for each Assessment so that we can compare it with `Amount` from the table `Assessment` as `AmountDue`. Plus if any Payment is not associated with any Assessment then don't do aggregation. The result would look like this:

```
+-----+-------+-----------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| AID | ASMID | AmountDue | PaymentsApplied |          ASM-Descr | PMT-Description |
+-----+-------+-----------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|   1 |     1 | 1200.0000 |       1100.0000 |               Rent |        Rent Fee |
|   1 |     2 |   20.0000 |         20.0000 | Damage - car break |     Damange Fee |
|   1 |     3 |  500.0000 |            NULL |   Damage - vehicle |            NULL |
|   1 |     0 |      NULL |        600.0000 |               NULL |     Deposit Fee |
|   1 |     0 |      NULL |         50.0000 |               NULL | Application Fee |
+-----+-------+-----------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------+
5 Rows
```

I tried my best to explain the situation. Actually, in my application query has joins over 10 tables like Agreement!

Any Help would be most welcome!!

---

### UPDATE 1

I've started from this query,

```
(SELECT DISTINCT
    Payment.RID, Payment.Amount as PaymentsApplied, Payment.ASMID as PMT_ASMID, null as AmountDue, null AS ASMID
FROM Payment
    LEFT JOIN Assessment ON Assessment.ASMID=Payment.ASMID)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT
    null, null, null, Assessment.Amount, Assessment.ASMID
FROM Assessment
    LEFT JOIN Payment ON Payment.ASMID=Assessment.ASMID)
ORDER BY ASMID, PMT_ASMID;
```

which gives me result,

```
+------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| RID  | PaymentsApplied | PMT_ASMID | AmountDue | ASMID |
+------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| NULL |            NULL |      NULL | 1200.0000 |     1 |
| NULL |            NULL |      NULL |   20.0000 |     2 |
| NULL |            NULL |      NULL |  500.0000 |     3 |
|    1 |        500.0000 |         1 |      NULL |  NULL |
|    2 |        600.0000 |         1 |      NULL |  NULL |
|    3 |         20.0000 |         2 |      NULL |  NULL |
|    4 |        600.0000 |         0 |      NULL |  NULL |
|    5 |         50.0000 |         0 |      NULL |  NULL |
+------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Now, from this point, IDK how to aggregate Payment rows by Assessment ID (ASMID) and do join with `Agreement` table also?

---

### UPDATE 2

I've made [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90f45/11) just in case someone wants to try it.

I've added conditional aggregation in my query,

```
(SELECT DISTINCT
    null as AmountDue,
    null AS ASMID,
    null as ASM_Descr,
    Payment.Description as PMT_Descr,
    (CASE WHEN Payment.ASMID > 0 THEN SUM(Payment.Amount) ELSE Payment.Amount END) as PaymentsApplied,
    (CASE WHEN Payment.ASMID > 0 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(Payment.RID) ELSE Payment.RID END) as PaymentList,
    Payment.ASMID as PMT_ASMID
FROM Payment
    LEFT JOIN Assessment ON Assessment.ASMID=Payment.ASMID
    GROUP BY Assessment.ASMID)
UNION ALL
(SELECT DISTINCT
    Assessment.Amount,
    Assessment.ASMID,
    Assessment.Description,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
FROM Assessment
    LEFT JOIN Payment ON Payment.ASMID=Assessment.ASMID
    GROUP BY Assessment.ASMID)
ORDER BY ASMID, PMT_ASMID;
```

which gives me,

```
+-----------+-------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
| AmountDue | ASMID | ASM_Descr          | PMT_Descr   | PaymentsApplied | PaymentList | PMT_ASMID |
+-----------+-------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
|      NULL |  NULL | NULL               | Deposit Fee |        600.0000 | 4           |         0 |
|      NULL |  NULL | NULL               | Rent Fee    |       1100.0000 | 1,2         |         1 |
|      NULL |  NULL | NULL               | Damage Fee  |         20.0000 | 3           |         2 |
| 1200.0000 |     1 | Rent               | NULL        |            NULL | NULL        |      NULL |
|   20.0000 |     2 | Damage - car break | NULL        |            NULL | NULL        |      NULL |
|  500.0000 |     3 | Damage - vehicle   | NULL        |            NULL | NULL        |      NULL |
+-----------+-------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
```

But, this one is still missing one row from Payment row (RID: 5) and I'm not getting the expected result.

Comment: Seems like you need to learn what right join does. (Instead of selecting those nulls.) Also, full join is a union, not union all, of left & right joins.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want a result row per AID + ASMID + PMT-Description. So:

1. Select from payments and aggregate.
2. Select from assessments.
3. Full outer join the two, as there can be payments without accessments and accessments without payments.

MySQL lacks `FULL OUTER JOIN`. So write the same query twice, once with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, once with `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, and use `UNION` on the two result sets.

```
select
  p.aid,
  p.asmid,
  a.amount as amount_due,
  p.payments_applied,
  a.description as asm_description,
  p.description as pmt_description
from
(
  select aid, asmid, description, sum(amount) as payments_applied
  from payment
  group by aid, asmid, description
) p
left join assessment a on a.aid = p.aid and a.asmid = p.asmid
union
select
  p.aid,
  p.asmid,
  a.amount as amount_due,
  p.payments_applied,
  a.description as asm_description,
  p.description as pmt_description
from
(
  select aid, asmid, description, sum(amount) as payments_applied
  from payment
  group by aid, asmid, description
) p
right join assessment a on a.aid = p.aid and a.asmid = p.asmid
order by aid, asmid, pmt_description;
```

Once MySQL features `FULL OUTER JOIN` you can cut this query in half.

Comment: You're right about the order of Grouping! I just want to ask a question, is your query more efficient than @JanZeiseweis's query?

Comment: @rsudip90: I don't know. I like to aggregate before joining in order to make it clearer what happens and to be less prome to errors when aggregations get added later. This query would be fine with a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. The LEFT/RIGHT/UNION is a simple workaround. It should be faster to select assessments with/without payments (outer join) and payments without assessments (no join, only `from payments`) and combine with `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` then.

Comment: @rsudip90 "more efficient" means nothing until *you* give *us* a definition including context & tradeoffs. If you don't know how to write a query, don't worry about writing an "efficient" one. Learn how to write a straightforward one.

Comment: Hi @philipxy, yes I agree with you! Actually, I wasn't meant to offend. But what Jan Zeiseweis did was logically make sense, I mean by looking at the first glance I got the idea and about Thorsten's answer, I literally had to brainstorm over the paper (maybe still I need to learn more!). Actually, you know what, I was confused that with which one should I go. Both queries give the same result, so the original aim was to know the technical difference in deep down for both. :) :)

Comment: BTW, @ThorstenKettner, I had to add one condition inside subquery at group by clause and that is `GROUP BY AID, CASE WHEN ASMID > 0 THEN ASMID ELSE RID END;` to achieve the expected result!

Answer (score 1):

I'd first collect all assessments, left join them to the payments and then union all payments without assessments:

```
# Assessments with payments

SELECT asm.AID,
       asm.ASMID,
       min(asm.Amount) AS AmountDue,
       SUM(pam.Amount) AS PaymentsApplied,
       asm.Description AS `ASM-Descr`,
       pam.Description AS `PMT-Descr`,
       agr.FLAGS
FROM Assessment asm
LEFT JOIN Payment pam ON pam.ASMID = asm.ASMID
JOIN Agreement agr ON agr.AID = asm.AID
GROUP BY asm.AID,
         asm.ASMID
UNION # Payments without assessments

SELECT pam.AID,
       pam.ASMID,
       NULL AS AmountDue,
       SUM(pam.Amount) AS PaymentsApplied,
       NULL AS `ASM-Descr`,
       pam.Description AS `PMT-Descr`,
       agr.FLAGS
FROM Payment pam
LEFT JOIN Assessment asm ON pam.ASMID = asm.ASMID
JOIN Agreement agr ON agr.AID = pam.AID
WHERE asm.ASMID IS NULL
GROUP BY pam.AID, pam.RID;
```

If you want to add more information you could wrap this result, give it a name and join more tables to the temporary result:

```
SELECT payment_overview.*,
       p.name
FROM
    ( # Assessments with payments
 SELECT asm.AID,
        asm.ASMID,
        min(asm.Amount) AS AmountDue,
        SUM(pam.Amount) AS PaymentsApplied,
        asm.Description AS `ASM-Descr`,
        pam.Description AS `PMT-Descr`,
        agr.FLAGS
     FROM Assessment asm
     LEFT JOIN Payment pam ON pam.ASMID = asm.ASMID
     JOIN Agreement agr ON agr.AID = asm.AID
     GROUP BY asm.AID,
              asm.ASMID
     UNION # Payments without assessments
 SELECT pam.AID,
        pam.ASMID,
        NULL AS AmountDue,
        SUM(pam.Amount) AS PaymentsApplied,
        NULL AS `ASM-Descr`,
        pam.Description AS `PMT-Descr`,
        agr.FLAGS
     FROM Payment pam
     LEFT JOIN Assessment asm ON pam.ASMID = asm.ASMID
     JOIN Agreement agr ON agr.AID = pam.AID
     WHERE asm.ASMID IS NULL
     GROUP BY pam.AID,
              pam.RID ) AS payment_overview
JOIN Payor p ON p.AID = payment_overview.AID ;
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the reply. Awesome! Another question, How could I fetch FLAGS from Agreement table. The reality is, after this, I've multiple joins over other 10 tables and I want to get some columns from those tables as well

Comment: I just added the flags.

Comment: What If I've another 10 tables, should I join them after Agreement table? and What is GROUP BY 1,2? I didn't get it actually!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind. The payment description in the first part could behave unexpected. Since you are aggregating the payment amounts (sum) you combine multiple payments. But since theres is no aggregation on the description and they could potentially different, you could get random results.

Comment: Right, I'm aware about that.

Comment: I changed the grouping to more explicit. `group by 1` means group by the first element in the select part. in this case it was asm.AID.

Comment: I don't know what your data structure looks like and what kind of information you want to add, so I can't help with this.

Comment: Let's say I've another table called `Payor` with three fields (`PID, Name, AID`)  and it has relation with Agreement and I want to see who is paying the amount then?

Comment: @rsudip90 I added the payer

Comment: Can I move JOIN over Agreement to above the line when you join over Payor?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. But did you try it?